# Embedding Google Analytic Charts on WebPage

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to embed charts from Google Analytic onto a webpage and allowing the public to view the charts without having to authenticate themselves?
I keep getting pointed to OAuth2, but I dont want my users to do any kind of logging in.

Some help please. 
Something similar to the question below, but he doesnt seemt to have found an answer.

[Google Analytics API in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373797/google-analytics-api-in-javascript/28059557?noredirect=1#comment44501510_28059557)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is all doable.  If you just want to show them your data not there own data then you can use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).   If you want to show them data from there own accounts then you have to go though Oauth2 and authenticate access to there account.

**Your Data**
You can't use a service account with JavaScript so you will have to do it yourself in the background in your C# code.

I recommend you use the [Google.apis.Analytics.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/) from nugget.  You can find a tutorial series on it here [Google Analytics API authentication with C#](http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/) as for displaying the charts check out [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

**Their data**
If you want to display there data and need to go though Oauth2 then the [Embeded API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) will do all this for you.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks for the reply. I shall look into that right away.

Comment: I have tried to use the sample project provided by you. Unfortunately I am stuck with a casting error, and I can't think of a way to solve that problem. Could you please help me out in this issue. The error is in you Management helper class regarding, allRows
@dalmto